# What is the most appropriate JSON-serialisable type to use here?

Tags: python, bcrypt, replit

Hi there developer folks,

I'm trying to write a little proof-of-concept program on repl.it which stores credentials securely using BCrypt. To save myself faffing with SQL, I'm prototyping using the built in repl.it database to store credentials.

The method in question is as follows:

```
def SignUp(self):
        '''Takes the username and password used to initialise the object, and stores them securely'''

        username = self.__username_input
        # Convert password input into bytes object
        password_bytes = bytes(self.__password_input, "UTF-8")
        # Hash password using the BCrypt algorithm
        hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(password_bytes, bcrypt.gensalt(rounds=14))
        
        username_available = True # True for testing - change to False for production

        # Checks if the username is available
        try:
            db[username]
        except KeyError:
            username_available = True

        if username_available:
            # Store password in database
            db[username] = hashed_password
            self.Username = username
            self.IsAuthenticated = True
            print(db[username])
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Currently, when I run this, I get the following error:

`TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`

Now I've tried changnig `db[username] = hashed_password` to `db[username] = str(hashed_password)`, which works fine, but then when I grab the hashed password back out of the database like so `bcrypt.checkpw(password_bytes, bytes(db[username], "UTF-8"))`, BCrypt throws this error:

`ValueError: Invalid salt`

Any suggestions would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: It helps if you tell us specifically which lines are generating the error messages you are describing.

Comment: Currently the error is coming from Line 20.

Comment: Just a reminder: Python adds values called `salt` to hash for security reasons. Salt value is different per python instances.

Comment: Oh yeah, I know, thanks though! I'm pretty sure in this case the salt is integrated into the final hash string produced by BCrypt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `db` supports only serializable objects.
Since I don't know what `db` is, in my outdated answer I assumed you were using a dictionary, but that's not true.

```py
# Store the password by encoding the bytes
db[username] = hashed_password.decode()

# Check it decoding the string
bcrypt.checkpw(password_bytes, db[username].encode())
```

**Differences between using `str()` and `bytes()`, and using `.encode()` and `.decode()`**

```py
password = '123123'
password_bytes = bytes(password, "UTF-8")

str_convert = str(password_bytes)
bytes_convert = bytes(str_convert, "UTF-8")
# str_convert = "b'123123'"
# bytes_convert = b"b'123123'"

decode = password_bytes.decode()
encode = decode.encode()
# decode = '123123'
# encode = b'123123'
```

Even though the first time you use `password_bytes = bytes(password, "UTF-8")` and it works, I don't recommend converting strings to bytes this way. It is better if you use `.encode()`

Comment: The issue is if I leave it alone, it throws the error TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable. I'm pretty sure it needs converting to something, I just can't figure out what.

Comment: Apologies for not clarifying. DB is the repl.it built in database.